# Testing automation tools to try for a Xamarin app

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, automated-tests, integration-testing

I am working on a Xamarin iOS app which later on is going to have an Android version as well. I am very new to Xamarin, in general. I was wondering if anyone has tried various testing automation tools out there and which one is the most recommended or what are the pros and cons of using them? Simple Google search returns Xamarin Test Cloud and Appium. There are also other lesser known solutions. I had the following factors in mind to assess these tools on:

1. Ease of writing the tests/learning curve involved in understanding the env. and language in which the tests are written
2. Integration of the test process work flow with Continuous Integration Server scripts

Please add the factors here that should be considered in assessing the right/better tool.

Comment: Please let me know if I could add more info. to this question to make it more precise.

Comment: https://wordpress.com/post/blog.kloud.com.au/44278 Check this out with sample application you can use

Answer (score 2):

[Xamarin Test Cloud](http://xamarin.com/test-cloud) is really cool, but kind of pricey. You can, however, run the UITests locally on the simulator or device. Xamarin has [great docs on getting started with UITests](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/cheatsheet/). There is also [NUnit](http://nunit.org/) and [xUnit](http://xunit.github.io/) that will allow you to write unit/integration tests.

If you're looking for CI or Testing information, Greg Shackles has done a few presentations on it: [Automated UI testing](https://speakerdeck.com/gshackles/automated-ui-testing-and-monitoring-for-your-mobile-apps), [Continuous Integration](https://speakerdeck.com/gshackles/using-continuous-integration-with-xamarin-apps), [CI sample on github](https://github.com/gshackles/xamarin-ci-sample).